# NSMutableArray that was able to unwrapped in Swiift2.2 becomes nil in Swift2.3

Tags: ios, swift2

As the title says the Array that could unwrapped in Swift2.2 turns to nil in Swift2.3(xcode8).

it happens in iOS10. Does somone knows the reason?

the self.dataObject is a json dictionary

```
var array : NSMutableArray?

override func viewDidLoad(){
    array = (self.dataObject as! NSDictionary)["array"] as? NSMutableArray
   print(array)
}
```

when i printed self.dataObject

```
Optional({
    attitude = 30;
    array =     (
                {
            attendance = "test1";
            bring = "test2";
            "id" = 503;
        },
                {
            attendance = "test1";
            bring = "test2";
            "id" = 504;
        }
                {
            attendance = "test1";
            bring = "test2";
            "id" = 505;
        }
    );
    second_id = n;
})
```

Comment: Can you add the results of `print(self.dataObject)` to your question?

Comment: Thanks for your replay i added it. Philip Mills

Comment: You talk about Swift 2.2 and 2.3 in the title but the tags are Swift 2.3 and 3. What do you really mean? What version of Swift do you want your code to be in?

Comment: rmaddy  I'm sorry, i deleted the swift3.0 tag. i meaned by swift2.3

Comment: @RyuEutsugu, can you plz show the code where you are serialising your JSON string?

Comment: Al always, do not use mutable Foundation collection types in Swift. They are not related to the Swift counterparts and you will throw away the type information. Use Swift native collection types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the array is immutable in this case. Therefore, it would be necessary to init a new mutable array from an immutable one.

Ex.
`array = NSMutableArray(array: ((self.dataObject as NSDictionary)["array"] as? NSArray)!)`